# How to get key from QuerySnapshot in android firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Here is an image of my database.]

Above is an image of my database.The three fields have other info linked to them.

I want to store the names of these three documents (Joke Writing, Negotiation, Psychology) in a list.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
List<String> na = new ArrayList<>();
        db.collection("courses").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            for(DocumentSnapshot document:task.getResult().getDocuments()){
                    na.add((String) document.get("key"));
            }
            Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(na));
        });
```

However, `na` is printing `[null,null,null]`. How can I get the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads a field called `key` from each document, and it looks like no such field exits.

If you instead want to get the document ID for each document, that'd be:

```
na.add(document.getId());
```

I recommend keeping the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) handy for this type of problem.